# How to parse a time (hours, minutes) -from a string by using regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I need to parse a string in order to get a valid time (hours and secondes).

Here is an example of the source data :

```
7:00-7:30
7:30-8:00
8:00-8:30
...
19:30-20:00
```

I only need the first time value.
So for the firt line i need to get "7:00".
Moreover the hour part can have one or two digit (7:00 / 20:00).

Any idea to get that ?

Comment: Line three of your input uses a colon to separate the first and second times, the other lines use a hyphen. Is this intended or a typo?

Comment: This is a typo, sorry. The only character is "-".

Comment: Is that example of the source data exact? If so: `^\d\{1,2}:\d\{2}`

Comment: You don't need a regex for this, and it would be a poorer approach. Use `String.Split` to divide the line and then use [`TimeSpan.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.tryparseexact.aspx) to validate as a time. This will handle things like the maximum number of the minutes in an hour (while possible that is much harder in a regex).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want a Timespan?

```
 var str = "7:00-7:30";
 var time = TimeSpan.Parse(str.Split('-')[0]);
```

if not, you can use

```
 var hours = str.Split('-')[0].Split(':')[0];
 var minutes = str.Split('-')[0].Split(':')[1];
```

the data you're looking for is unchanging from line to line, so a regex isn't really necessary here.

Comment: Making use of `TimeSpan.TryParseExact` allows a specific `TimeSpan` format *and* avoids the exception when not in the right format.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a regex. Just split it on the `-` which will return an array of which the first element at 0 index will contain what you want.

```
string date = "7:00-7:30"; bool val = date.IndexOf("-") > -1;
var splitter = val ? "-" : ":";
var arr = date.Split(splitter);
var firstpart = val ? arr[0] : arr[0] + ':' + arr[1];
```

Comment: @Richard The OP has agreed and changed the question.  Rescinding my downvote.

Comment: I would like to use regex to check if the it's a valid time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex of the form

```
^(?:1?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-6][0-9]
```

For example : http://regex101.com/r/fM3kL7/1

```
var re = /^(?:1?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-6][0-9]/gm;
var str = '7:00-7:30\n7:30-8:00\n8:00-8:30\n...\n19:30-20:00';
var res = str.match(re);
```

Will give an output as

```
7:00,7:30,8:00,19:30
```